# Can ffmpeg transcode an audio track and add it as a second audio track at the same time, or if not, how to do it as separate commands?

Tags: audio, video, ffmpeg

A bit of history. I am using Plex as my media server, but for reasons unknown, it has issues transcoding the DTS-HD MA 7.1 audio to EAC3 stereo and keeps buffering (the server has plenty of horsepower on all fronts, CPU/RAM/drive space & speed, gigabit networks connections for all devices. The playback device (TCL Roku TV, with a 3rd party soundbar connected via HDMI ARC) doesn't support the built-in 7.1 audio, so I get silence if I play it back directly by putting the file on a USB stick.

Also, I am by no means a ffmpeg guru, I figured out what I do know by Google University and asking questions, so please be kind and forgive me if I ask follow-up questions that may seem n00b-ish, and please provide example commands (preferably in the context of my command below so that I can have a known point of reference to start with).

I have a movie with 4K (HEVC Main 10 HDR) video and DTS-HD MA 7.1 audio that I am looking to leave the video and audio untouched, but to add a 2nd audio track in either EAC3 or if necessary, just AC3 in stereo

So what I am looking for is as follows:

video.mkv

- Existing->4k video file (no change)
- Existing->7.1 audio (no change)
- Convert and add->stereo audio as a 2nd audio track to the output.mkv file

Below is the command I've historically used with ffmpeg to convert and replace the audio file with the stereo audio, but since I'd prefer to leave the 7.1 audio in place, this doesn't work:
`ffmpeg -i "D:\video.mkv" -c:v copy -c:a aac -b:a 128k "D:\output.mkv"`

And if this cannot be done as a single command, please also let me know what steps I do need to take to be able to do it.

Thanks in advace,
Mike

Answer (score -1):

```
ffmpeg -i input.mkv -map 0 -map 0:a -c copy -c:a:1 eac3 output.mkv
```

- `-map 0` select all streams.
- `-map 0:a` select all audio streams. This combines with `-map 0` so now you have 1 video and 2 audio streams selected.
- `-c copy` stream copy all streams.
- `-c:a:1 eac3` encode output audio stream #1 with eac3 encoder. This overrides `-c copy` for this particular stream.